Transform and manipulate objects within JSON. Dot issue
I have the following JSON and I would like to transform it with Jolt.
JSON Input
{
  "orderNo": "4800001",
  "resourceCode": "test",
  "createdBy": "27150173",
  "action": "R",
  "personId": "R",
  "userId": "test",
  "extraFields": {
    "a": "test",
    "b": "test"
  }
}

Jolt Transform tried
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "orderNo": {
        "#orderNo": "urn:ietf:params:scim:schemas:sailpoint:1.0:LaunchedWorkflow.input[0].key",
        "@": "urn:ietf:params:scim:schemas:sailpoint:1.0:LaunchedWorkflow.input[0].value"
      },
      "createdBy": {
        "#identityName": "urn:ietf:params:scim:schemas:sailpoint:1.0:LaunchedWorkflow.input[1].key",
        "@": "urn:ietf:params:scim:schemas:sailpoint:1.0:LaunchedWorkflow.input[1].value"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "default",
    "spec": {
      "schemas": [
        "urn:ietf:params:scim:schemas:sailpoint:1.0:LaunchedWorkflow",
        "urn:ietf:params:scim:schemas:sailpoint:1.0:TaskResult"
      ],
      "urn:ietf:params:scim:schemas:sailpoint:1.0:LaunchedWorkflow": {
        "workflowName": "Fix"
      }
    }
  }
]

Current Output
{
  "urn:ietf:params:scim:schemas:sailpoint:1": {
    "0:LaunchedWorkflow": {
      "input": [
        {
          "key": "orderNo",
          "value": "test"
        },
        {
          "key": "identityName",
          "value": "test"
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "schemas": [
    "urn:ietf:params:scim:schemas:sailpoint:1.0:LaunchedWorkflow",
    "urn:ietf:params:scim:schemas:sailpoint:1.0:TaskResult"
  ],
  "urn:ietf:params:scim:schemas:sailpoint:1.0:LaunchedWorkflow": {
    "workflowName": "Fix"
  }
}

Desired Output
{
  "schemas": [
    "urn:ietf:params:scim:schemas:sailpoint:1.0:LaunchedWorkflow",
    "urn:ietf:params:scim:schemas:sailpoint:1.0:TaskResult"
  ],
  "urn:ietf:params:scim:schemas:sailpoint:1.0:LaunchedWorkflow": {
    "workflowName": "Fix",
    "input": [
      {
        "key": "orderNo",
        "value": "4800001"
      },
      {
        "key": "identityName",
        "value": "27150173"
      }
    ]
  }
}

The problem is, that I do not know how to handle the dot inside "urn:ietf:params:scim:schemas:sailpoint:1.0:LaunchedWorkflow", so it will act as a string (and won't cut it because of the dot).
What should be the Jolt spec?

Need to use double backslashes(\\) in order to be able to escape special characters such as dots. So, you can rewrite the specifcation as follows :
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "#Fix": "urn:ietf:params:scim:schemas:sailpoint:1\\.0:LaunchedWorkflow.workflowName",
      "orderNo": {
        "#orderNo": "urn:ietf:params:scim:schemas:sailpoint:1\\.0:LaunchedWorkflow.input[0].key",
        "@": "urn:ietf:params:scim:schemas:sailpoint:1\\.0:LaunchedWorkflow.input[0].value"
      },
      "createdBy": {
        "#identityName": "urn:ietf:params:scim:schemas:sailpoint:1\\.0:LaunchedWorkflow.input[1].key",
        "@": "urn:ietf:params:scim:schemas:sailpoint:1\\.0:LaunchedWorkflow.input[1].value"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "default",
    "spec": {
      "schemas": [
        "urn:ietf:params:scim:schemas:sailpoint:1.0:LaunchedWorkflow",
        "urn:ietf:params:scim:schemas:sailpoint:1.0:TaskResult"
      ]
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "sort"
  }
]

the demo on the site Jolt Transform Demo Using v0.1.1 is :

Indeed, using only such a shift transformation suffices :
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "#urn:ietf:params:scim:schemas:sailpoint:1.0:LaunchedWorkflow|#urn:ietf:params:scim:schemas:sailpoint:1.0:TaskResult": "schemas",
      "#Fix": "urn:ietf:params:scim:schemas:sailpoint:1\\.0:LaunchedWorkflow.workflowName",
      "orderNo": {
        "#orderNo": "urn:ietf:params:scim:schemas:sailpoint:1\\.0:LaunchedWorkflow.input[0].key",
        "@": "urn:ietf:params:scim:schemas:sailpoint:1\\.0:LaunchedWorkflow.input[0].value"
      },
      "createdBy": {
        "#identityName": "urn:ietf:params:scim:schemas:sailpoint:1\\.0:LaunchedWorkflow.input[1].key",
        "@": "urn:ietf:params:scim:schemas:sailpoint:1\\.0:LaunchedWorkflow.input[1].value"
      }
    }
  }
]

Notice that, escaping for the special chars is not needed if the expression is on the right-hand-side and prefixed by #(fixed one)
Btw, a cleaner code, in which indexes not written one by one such as [0] and [1] , with less hardcoding would be enough for the case if both keys orderNo and createdBy would exactly replicated such as
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "#urn:ietf:params:scim:schemas:sailpoint:1.0:LaunchedWorkflow|#urn:ietf:params:scim:schemas:sailpoint:1.0:TaskResult": "schemas",
      "#Fix": "urn:ietf:params:scim:schemas:sailpoint:1\\.0:LaunchedWorkflow.workflowName",
      "orderNo|createdBy": {
        "$": "urn:ietf:params:scim:schemas:sailpoint:1\\.0:LaunchedWorkflow.input[#2].key",
        "@": "urn:ietf:params:scim:schemas:sailpoint:1\\.0:LaunchedWorkflow.input[#2].value"
      }
    }
  }
]

so as to get the output as
{
  "schemas" : [ "urn:ietf:params:scim:schemas:sailpoint:1.0:LaunchedWorkflow", "urn:ietf:params:scim:schemas:sailpoint:1.0:TaskResult" ],
  "urn:ietf:params:scim:schemas:sailpoint:1.0:LaunchedWorkflow" : {
    "workflowName" : "Fix",
    "input" : [ {
      "key" : "orderNo",
      "value" : "4800001"
    }, {
      "key" : "createdBy", //not "identityName"
      "value" : "27150173"
    } ]
  }
}


I've tested your suggestion including the double backslashes (\) and It works perfect.
Thank you!

Putting the double \ worked for me, like this:
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "orderNo": {
        "#orderNo": "urn:ietf:params:scim:schemas:sailpoint:1\\.0:LaunchedWorkflow.input[0].key",
        "@": "urn:ietf:params:scim:schemas:sailpoint:1\\.0:LaunchedWorkflow.input[0].value"
      },
      "createdBy": {
        "#identityName": "urn:ietf:params:scim:schemas:sailpoint:1\\.0:LaunchedWorkflow.input[1].key",
        "@": "urn:ietf:params:scim:schemas:sailpoint:1\\.0:LaunchedWorkflow.input[1].value"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "default",
    "spec": {
      "schemas": [
        "urn:ietf:params:scim:schemas:sailpoint:1.0:LaunchedWorkflow",
        "urn:ietf:params:scim:schemas:sailpoint:1.0:TaskResult"
      ],
      "urn:ietf:params:scim:schemas:sailpoint:1.0:LaunchedWorkflow": {
        "workflowName": "Fix"
      }
    }
  }
]


Let me know if this is what you are looking for.
